# CMake is not using correct paths when looking for lib files

Tags: c++, cmake, vcpkg

I recently installed vcpkg on my windows system and the cmake (and cmake tools) extension for vscode, because I wanted to use a json file for my c++ project. I had put vcpkg in a random location just to mess around with it and learn how it works. However, when I moved it to another location as its final spot, CMake got confused and couldn't find lib files for jsoncpp.

Here's the error:

> Unable to open 'json_value.cpp': Unable to read file 'c:\path\to\old\location\vcpkg\buildtrees\jsoncpp\src\3918c327b1-034a82149a.clean\src\lib_json\json_value.cpp' (Error: Unable to resolve non-existing file 'c:\path\to\old\location\vcpkg\buildtrees\jsoncpp\src\3918c327b1-034a82149a.clean\src\lib_json\json_value.cpp').

I had moved vcpkg from `C:\path\to\old\location\vcpkg` to `C:\vcpkg`

And here's my CMakeLists.txt file:

```cmake
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(myProgram VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

add_executable(myProgram main.cpp)

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
# set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR})
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE debug)
# set_target_properties(${PROJECT_NAME}
# PROPERTIES 
# RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_DEBUG ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
include(CPack)

include_directories(C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include)
link_directories(C:/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib)

find_package(jsoncpp CONFIG REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE jsoncpp_lib jsoncpp_object)
```

I have already tried updating the CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE property in settings.json, deleting cmake's cache, resetting the extension, and reinstalling jsoncpp, vcpkg and the cmake extensions fresh (I had made sure that their files were deleted).

Comment: ***had put vcpkg in a random location just to mess around with it and learn how it works. However, when I moved it to another location as its final spot*** My advice is to delete your vcpkg folder and start fresh.

Comment: @drescherjm I had. At the end of the question, I had stated that I had done a fresh install by deleting the files and reinstalled it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to take out the find package function. The find package function made cmake expect the source code to be in the buildtrees folder, which in this case isn't (I think it was at some point, but I don't know why it wont come back). Just by using `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} jsoncpp)`, as well as the include/link directories statements gave cmake everything it needed to include the library. One thing I still don't understand however is why cmake was looking in the old location for that bit of source code.